# Is the Dual Savagery perk multiplied by the Assassins Blade perk?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From [elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_(Skyrim)](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_%28Skyrim%29):

> Assassin's Blade
>
> Sneak attacks with daggers now do a total of fifteen times normal damage.

From [elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/One-Handed](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/One-Handed):

> Dual Savagery
>
> Dual wielding power attacks do 50% bonus damage.

My question is, assuming I have both perks, am wielding two identical weapons and my weapon damage is X, will I do 2X * 15 * 1.5 = 45X damage or 2X * 15 + (2X * 1.5) = 33X damage?

If anyone is able to back up an answer with examples from in-game, that would be great.

Note: Don't consider the Armsman perk, the damage multiplier from one-handed skill and the damage multiplier for power attack vs regular attacks. I left them out deliberately for clarity, as I already know they stack.

Comment: I'm curious, why use wikia instead of the UESP?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Probably doesn't know about UESP, wikia sites just tend to show up first in searches. It's particularly bad with TF2, the wikia site shows up before the official wiki and the information is just bad.

Comment: @RavenDreamer First search result for what I wanted. Assuming wikia isn't changing the perk's official name and description, it's sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this out in-game and yes, it does stack as in your first example.

Using a steel dagger with 10 display damage (10.36 actual) and the Dark Brotherhood gloves, I achieved 932.4 damage; without the perk, 621.6. The exact damage formula without the sneak bonus [from UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons#Overview) is as follows:

```
Damage = 
((Right Hand displayed Damage * (1 + Power Attack Bonus) * (1 + Dual Power Attack Bonus) * (1 + Power Attack Perk) * (1 + Dual Power Attack perk)) * Dual Power Attack Mod)
+ ((Left Hand displayed Damage * (1 + Power Attack Bonus) * (1 + Dual Power Attack Bonus) * (1 + Power Attack Perk) * (1 + Dual Power Attack perk)) * Dual Power Attack Mod)

Power Attack Bonus = 1 if power attacking
Dual Power Attack Bonus = 0.125 if power attacking with dual weapons
Power Attack Perk = 0.25 if power attacking and you have Savage Strike or Devastating Blow
Dual Power Attack Perk = 0.5 if power attacking with two weapons and you have Dual Savagery
Dual Power Attack Mod is 2/3 for the right and 1/3 for the left hand
```

As the wiki notes, you don't actually need to attack with both weapons to get the bonus, just have 2 equipped.